# Soap webservice in android

Tags: android

hai i am kamal i am new in android and while i running my program i got the error in logcat in the following error

.plz provide a suitable way to connect and got response

```
03-09 12:00:38.639: WARN/System.err(220): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43d464c0) 
03-09 12:00:38.690: WARN/System.err(220):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:245)
03-09 12:00:38.700: WARN/System.err(220):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:1376)
03-09 12:00:38.717: WARN/System.err(220):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
03-09 12:00:38.720: WARN/System.err(220):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
03-09 12:00:38.720: WARN/System.err(220):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
03-09 12:00:38.720: WARN/System.err(220):     at com.devstream.http.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
03-09 12:00:38.740: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
03-09 12:00:38.750: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
03-09 12:00:38.771: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
03-09 12:00:38.801: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-09 12:00:38.801: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-09 12:00:38.811: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-09 12:00:38.821: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-09 12:00:38.832: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-09 12:00:38.841: WARN/System.err(220):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
03-09 12:00:38.850: WARN/System.err(220):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-09 12:00:38.860: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
03-09 12:00:38.870: WARN/System.err(220):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
03-09 12:00:38.889: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
03-09 12:00:38.889: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 12:00:38.889: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-09 12:00:38.899: WARN/System.err(220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-09 12:00:38.912: WARN/System.err(220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 12:00:38.919: WARN/System.err(220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-09 12:00:38.930: WARN/System.err(220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-09 12:00:38.939: WARN/System.err(220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-09 12:00:38.959: WARN/System.err(220):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to connect to a SOAP web service. But, the web service is returning HTML response instead of SOAP response. You can use tools like SOAP UI to test your web service and then consume it from your android program.

Comment: how i use soap UI tool please provide detail way

Answer (score 0):

There may be an error in the input parameters that you are sending to the soap service. Make sure that adding input parameters to the SOAP service (request) is as follows:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "yourFunctionName");

request.addProperty("dbuser", dbuser); // addProperty rather than addAttribute.
```

And to obtain output parameters from the SOAP service (the consumption part):

```
androidHttpTransport.call("yourFunctionName", env);

SoapObject result = (SoapObject) env.bodyIn;
```

Then call the `getProperty(int)` method to obtain all the properties you intended to consume.